# Changing Model property based on different button click in Razor view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have two buttons for one single form in my Razor view, I want to set one of the model property  on the basis of which button is clicked to submit the form. Code below explains why I needed two different buttons to submit one single form.

Form in my Razor view:

```
    @model BTSWeb.Models.DropDownModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("BillAccounts", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id="onDemandForm"}))
{

        <span style="margin-left:315px"></span>  

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.server1)
     <br/> <br/>

    <label style="color:black">    

                <span style="margin-left:40px"></span>  

            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.billText)

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.billchecker, new { id ="billchecker"})
            <span style="margin-left:0px"></span>  

<input id="Button4" type="button" value="On-Demand Bill" onclick="submitOnDemandForm()" />

                <span style="margin-left:50px"></span>  

<input id="Button5" type="button" value="Force Bill" onclick="submitForceBillForm()" />



<br/>    <br/>


}
```

Jquery functions bound to the onclick of above buttons:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#onDemandForm>input").addClass("importGroupOnDemandBill");

    });

   function submitOnDemandForm() {



        $("#ddlform>input.importGroupOnDemandBill").remove();
        var $inputs3 = $("#onDemandForm>input").clone();
        //var $inputs2 = $("#server2form>input").clone();
        $("#ddlform").append($inputs3);
        //$("#ddlform").append($inputs2);
        $inputs3.css('display', 'none');

        //submit
        $('#ddlform').attr('action', '/Home/BillAccounts');

        document.getElementById("ddlform").submit();
    }
    function submitForceBillForm() {


        $("#ddlform>input.importGroupOnDemandBill").remove();
        var $inputs4 = $("#onDemandForm>input").clone();
        //var $inputs2 = $("#server2form>input").clone();
        $("#ddlform").append($inputs4);
        //$("#ddlform").append($inputs2);
        $inputs4.css('display', 'none');

        //submit
        $('#ddlform').attr('action', '/Home/BillAccounts');
        document.getElementById("ddlform").submit();
    }

</script>
```

There is a property billcheker in my dropdownview model, I want to set it as "1" if Button4 is clicked and as "2" if Button5 is clicked after the form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "hidden field" for the billcheker property in html, like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.billcheker)
```

And in jQuery set the value of this textbox, like this:

```
 function submitOnDemandForm() {

       $("#ddlform>input.importGroupOnDemandBill").remove();
        var $inputs3 = $("#onDemandForm>input").clone();
        //var $inputs2 = $("#server2form>input").clone();
        $("#ddlform").append($inputs3);
        //$("#ddlform").append($inputs2);
        $inputs3.css('display', 'none');

        document.getElementById("billcheker").value = "1"; // set value of hidden field
        //submit
        $('#ddlform').attr('action', '/Home/BillAccounts');
        document.getElementById("ddlform").submit();
    }

    function submitForceBillForm() {

        $("#ddlform>input.importGroupOnDemandBill").remove();
        var $inputs4 = $("#onDemandForm>input").clone();
        //var $inputs2 = $("#server2form>input").clone();
        $("#ddlform").append($inputs4);
        //$("#ddlform").append($inputs2);
        $inputs4.css('display', 'none');

        document.getElementById("billcheker").value = "2"; // set value of hidden field
        //submit
        $('#ddlform').attr('action', '/Home/BillAccounts');
        document.getElementById("ddlform").submit();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I tried what you said but my code is executing after the line where you set the values in hiddenfor field. Also, I am not very sure if getelementbyname would recognize billchecker, since it's a model property.

Comment: It should recognize, if not then just change that to getElementById.

Comment: Code is working now, I have updated the code, but model property is still not being set.

Comment: It worked after putting the value set line at the top most in the function. Thank so much.

Comment: Great! Please accept/vote this answer is you feel happy with this.